# Getting Datefield after Today and Before another date not returning the expected object

Tags: python, django

I am writing an app in Django where I have created a PayPeriods model as such:

```
class PayPeriods(models.Model):
    first_day = models.DateField(default=date.today)
    last_day = models.DateField(default=date.today)
    pay_day = models.DateField(default=date.today)
```

I've created a small function that allows me to get the current PP through my app,

```
def get_pp():
    _pp = PayPeriods.objects.filter(first_day__gte=datetime.today(),last_day__lt=datetime.today())[0]
    return _pp
```

but its not returning as expected.

What am I missing?

Current day today is 11/29/2022, so I am expecting to return Obj #4, as the code is written.

```
PP Object #3: first_day = 11/13/22, last_day = 11/26/22
PP Ojbect #4: first_day = 11/17/22, last_day = 12/10/22
PP Ojbect #5: first_day = 12/11/22, last_day = 12/24/22
```

I have verified that my dates are formatted the same way, (stored data & datetime.today(), and my timezone settings are correct.).

Comment: If I understand your data correctly I think you just use the wrong lookups, you want lte for the first day and gte for the last day - `filter(first_day__lte=datetime.today(), last_day__gte=datetime.today())`

Comment: When first_day is greater or equal to today ... the PayPeriod will be in the future. Check your logic.